# Preserve content when merging maps with same key

Tags: merge, terraform, concatenation

Terraform Deep Merge Functionality without losing the content of the key and merging the content.

```
locals {
  mgmt-split = {
    lob_v2 = {
      "npe" = {
        "shared001" = {
          "environments" = toset([
            {
              "environment"     = "shared001npevalue"
              "subscription_id" = "subid_shared001-npe-value"
            }
          ])
        }
      }
      "prd" = {
        "shared001" = {
          "environments" = toset([
            {
              "environment"     = "shared001prdvalue"
              "subscription_id" = "subid_shared001-prd-value"
            }
          ])
        }
        "shared002" = {
          "environments" = toset([
            {
              "environment"     = "shared002prdvalue"
              "subscription_id" = "subid_shared002-prd-value"
            }
          ])
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to squash/ignore the environments "npe" and "prd".

This code squashes the environments

```
locals {
  mgmt = [
    for env, lobs in local.mgmt-split.lob_v2 : {
      for lob, environments in lobs : lob => {
        "environments" = [for e in environments.environments : {
          "environment"     = e.environment
          "subscription_id" = e.subscription_id
        }]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The output looks like this

```
[
  {
    "shared001" = {
      "environments" = [
        {
          "environment" = "shared001npevalue"
          "subscription_id" = "subid_shared001-npe-value"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "shared001" = {
      "environments" = [
        {
          "environment" = "shared001prdvalue"
          "subscription_id" = "subid_shared001-prd-value"
        },
      ]
    }
    "shared002" = {
      "environments" = [
        {
          "environment" = "shared002prdvalue"
          "subscription_id" = "subid_shared002-prd-value"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
]
```

Now I need to merge the same key items but using the merge function gets rid of the content like the environments and only outputs the later key value like this.

```
merged = {
  "shared001" = {
    "environments" = [
      {
        "environment" = "shared001prdvalue"
        "subscription_id" = "subid_shared001-prd-value"
      },
    ]
  }
  "shared002" = {
    "environments" = [
      {
        "environment" = "shared002prdvalue"
        "subscription_id" = "subid_shared002-prd-value"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

I need the environments block for "shared001" concatenated to include the subscription for npe and prd like this ... This is the expected output.

```
merged = {
  "shared001" = {
    "environments" = [
      {
        "environment" = "shared001npevalue"
        "subscription_id" = "subid_shared001-npe-value"
      },
      {
        "environment" = "shared001prdvalue"
        "subscription_id" = "subid_shared001-prd-value"
      },
    ]
  }
  "shared002" = {
    "environments" = [
      {
        "environment" = "shared002prdvalue"
        "subscription_id" = "subid_shared002-prd-value"
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried the deepmerge custom function but no luck either

Comment: I would speculate this kind of data structure transformation would be brutal in HCL2 for arbitrary type/structure inputs (I normally attempt every TF coding challenge, and this one is giving me pause), and you would probably need to do something in Go and make that available as a `data` (or another language and `external_data`). If someone proves me wrong then I regret that I have but one upvote to give.

Comment: I think the specific reason this would be difficult is because of HCL2's insistence in its AST/parser/etc. that `for` expressions and their nested expressions be wrapped within constructors (I would really appreciate an explanation on that decision at some point). This causes e.g. your result where it is nested within singular set/list/block/map.

Answer (score 0):

Although you've described this as "deep merge", the example result you shared seems more like grouping the environments together by a "lob" (line of business?).

If approaching it from that standpoint then it seems like the kind of problem that can be solved using [a `for` expression's ability to group by key](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/for#grouping-results).

I would start by flattening this structure even further so that it's easier to work with:

```
locals {
  environments = flatten([
    for group in local.mgmt : [
      for lob, lob_envs in group : [
        for env in lob_envs.environments : {
          environment     = env.environment
          subscription_id = env.subscription_id
          lob             = lob
        }
      ]
    ]
  ])
}
```

The result of the above should be:

```
[
  {
    environment     = "shared001npevalue"
    subscription_id = "subid_shared001-npe-value"
    lob             = "shared001"
  },
  {
    environment     = "shared001prdvalue"
    subscription_id = "subid_shared001-prd-value"
    lob             = "shared001"
  },
  {
    environment     = "shared002prdvalue"
    subscription_id = "subid_shared002-prd-value"
    lob             = "shared002"
  },
]
```

With the above it's possible to project one more time to group by the `lob` attribute:

```
locals {
  environments_by_lob = tomap({
    for env in local.environments : env.lob => env...
  })
}
```

That should produce this result:

```
tomap({
  "shared001" = [
    {
      environment     = "shared001npevalue"
      subscription_id = "subid_shared001-npe-value"
      lob             = "shared001"
    },
    {
      environment     = "shared001prdvalue"
      subscription_id = "subid_shared001-prd-value"
      lob             = "shared001"
    },
  ]
  "shared002" = [
    {
      environment     = "shared002prdvalue"
      subscription_id = "subid_shared002-prd-value"
      lob             = "shared002"
    },
  ]
})
```

This now has the same fundamental shape as the data structure you showed as your desired output: each distinct "lob" key has its own list of environments.

If it's important to structure it *exactly* as you showed it, with the intermediate `environments` attribute that has the list assigned to it, then one more projection could achieve that:

```
locals {
  lobs = tomap({
    for lob, envs in local.environments_by_lob : lob => {
      environments = toset(envs)
    }
  })
}
```

Now this final result should be:

```
tomap({
  "shared001" = {
    environments = toset([
      {
        environment     = "shared001npevalue"
        subscription_id = "subid_shared001-npe-value"
        lob             = "shared001"
      },
      {
        environment     = "shared001prdvalue"
        subscription_id = "subid_shared001-prd-value"
        lob             = "shared001"
      },
    ])
  ]
  "shared002" = {
    environments = toset([
      {
        environment     = "shared002prdvalue"
        subscription_id = "subid_shared002-prd-value"
        lob             = "shared002"
      },
    ])
  ]
})
```